# Updating to use Option Strict On

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I am working on updating a VB.net project to use Option Strict On throughout and seeing this error:

> BC32013 Option Strict On disallows operands of type Object for operator '='. Use the 'Is' operator to test for object identity.

However when I try it the code does not work.

Code:

```
If (dtg_FieldSelector.Rows.Item(m_int_SelectedRow).Cells(0).Value = txt_FieldIndex.Text) Then
```

Comment: Please can you provide more lines of code? E.g. variable declarations, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to stringify the datagrid value as it is `Object` and Strict on forbids the comparison of two different datatypes

```
If (dtg_FieldSelector.Rows.Item(m_int_SelectedRow).Cells(0).Value.ToString() = txt_FieldIndex.Text) Then
```